# Laravel Edit Post Content using CKeditor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, laravel-5

I am trying to edit existing post using CKeditor. Content isn't loading.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Content</label>
<textarea id="editor1"  name="content" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Enter ...">
{{ Request::old('content') }}
</textarea>
</div>
```

Also im having trouble getting date from the database too.

```
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</div>
<input type="date" name="published_at" class="form-control" value="{{ $post->published_at->format('M jS Y') }}">
</div>
```

Comment: what trouble are you having with the date, specifically? also you probably want to pull the content for the textarea from the old input, with a fallback to using the model's content attribute.

Comment: {{ Request::old('content') }} is what i used, and it's not showing me anything.

Comment: you should be pulling the content from the model as there might not be any 'old' input if you haven't submitted the form and been redirected back.

Comment: I am trying to pull an existing post from edit function in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the textarea, check for old input, but fall back to defaulting to using the model's content attribute (the post's content)

```
<textarea ....>{!! Request::old('content', $post->content) !!}</textarea>
```

For your date issue, I don't know what problem you are having.

Comment: However in CK5 using the default escaped secure syntax {{ $post->content }} worked perfectly with images, mentions (users, tags) etc. Thanks